# unable to loop through nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to loop through the following array but did not succeed,

is my approach correct?
I have done many changes to my code it might be not as it was

my try :

```
var gender = ["men", "women"];
var category = [
    "topwear",
    "bottomwear",
    "indianwear",
    "westernwear",
];

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    for (var g = 0; g < gender.length; g++) {
        for (j = 0; j < categories[i][gender[g]].length; j++) {
            for (var c = 0; c < category.length; c++) {
                console.log("=======category========", category[c]);
                for (k = 0; k < categories[i][gender[g]][j][category[c]].length; k++) {
                    console.log(categories[i][gender[g]][j][category[c]][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the array :

```
 [
    {
        men: [
            {
                topwear: [
                    "men-topwear",
                    "men-tshirts",
                    "men-casual-shirts",
                    "men-formal-shirts",
                    "men-sweatshirts",
                    "men-sweaters",
                    "men-jackets",
                    "men-blazers",
                    "men-suits",
                    "rain-jacket",
                ],
            },
            {
                bottomwear: [
                    "men-jeans",
                    "men-casual-trousers",
                    "men-formal-trousers",
                    "mens-shorts",
                    "men-trackpants",
                    "men-innerwear",
                    "men-briefs-and-trunks",
                    "men-boxers",
                    "men-innerwear-vests",
                    "men-nightwear",
                    "men-thermals",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        women: [
            {
                indianwear: [
                    "women-kurtas-kurtis-suits",
                    "ethnic-tops",
                    "ethnic-wear-dresses-menu",
                    "women-ethnic-bottomwear?f=categories%3AChuridar%2CLeggings%2CSalwar",
                    "skirts-palazzos",
                    "saree",
                    "dress-material",
                    "lehenga-choli",
                    "dupatta-shawl",
                    "women-ethnic-wear-jackets",
                    "dresses?f=Gender%3Amen%20women%2Cwomen",
                    "jumpsuits?f=Gender%3Amen%20women%2Cwomen",
                ],
            },
            {
                westernwear: [
                    "women-shirts-tops-tees",
                    "women-jeans-jeggings",
                    "women-trousers",
                    "women-shorts-skirts",
                    "women-shrugs",
                    "women-sweaters-sweatshirts",
                    "women-jackets-coats",
                    "women-blazers-waistcoats",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I need to get the names within the array.
coz i need to use it in the code which i am going to write inside the inner
most loop.

thanks in advance

Comment: `men:` and `women:` should be in the same object, not different objects.

Comment: ohh.
can u pls provide solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code expects each object in the array to have both `men` and `women` properties. But these properties are in separate array elements. So you need to check whether the property exists before trying to loop over its elements. Otherwise you'll try to get the length of an undefined property.

Similarly, each object in the `men` or `women` array has just a single property, not all the properties in the `category` array.

Looping will be much easier if you assign variables to the current element of the array, so you don't need long expressions with lots of indexes like `categories[i][gender[g]][j][category[c]][k]`. And using `forEach()` will simplify this.

```js
var gender = ["men", "women"];
var category = [
  "topwear",
  "bottomwear",
  "indianwear",
  "westernwear",
];

var categories = [{
    men: [{
        topwear: [
          "men-topwear",
          "men-tshirts",
          "men-casual-shirts",
          "men-formal-shirts",
          "men-sweatshirts",
          "men-sweaters",
          "men-jackets",
          "men-blazers",
          "men-suits",
          "rain-jacket",
        ],
      },
      {
        bottomwear: [
          "men-jeans",
          "men-casual-trousers",
          "men-formal-trousers",
          "mens-shorts",
          "men-trackpants",
          "men-innerwear",
          "men-briefs-and-trunks",
          "men-boxers",
          "men-innerwear-vests",
          "men-nightwear",
          "men-thermals",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    women: [{
        indianwear: [
          "women-kurtas-kurtis-suits",
          "ethnic-tops",
          "ethnic-wear-dresses-menu",
          "women-ethnic-bottomwear?f=categories%3AChuridar%2CLeggings%2CSalwar",
          "skirts-palazzos",
          "saree",
          "dress-material",
          "lehenga-choli",
          "dupatta-shawl",
          "women-ethnic-wear-jackets",
          "dresses?f=Gender%3Amen%20women%2Cwomen",
          "jumpsuits?f=Gender%3Amen%20women%2Cwomen",
        ],
      },
      {
        westernwear: [
          "women-shirts-tops-tees",
          "women-jeans-jeggings",
          "women-trousers",
          "women-shorts-skirts",
          "women-shrugs",
          "women-sweaters-sweatshirts",
          "women-jackets-coats",
          "women-blazers-waistcoats",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

categories.forEach(catItem =>
  gender.forEach(genItem => {
    if (catItem[genItem]) {
      category.forEach(cat => {
        console.log("=======category========", cat);
        catItem[genItem].forEach(i => {
          if (i[cat]) {
            i[cat].forEach(x => console.log(x));
          }
        });
      });
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: its showing me

`for (k = 0; k < categories[i][gender[g]][j][category[c]].length; k++`

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined